# Space between header module and content module joomla in mobile browser

Tags: html, css, joomla

I'm currently developing a **Joomla** site for a client using **Joomla 3** and the **Helix framework**. The issue I'am having is that when I preview the site in a mobile browser there is a gap or space between the main menu bar and the main content (see attached picture).

**What I have tried**.
 - I've reset all browser margins and padding defaults to 0 using the following methods:

```
{padding:0; margin:0;} 
html {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

- I've installed `normalize.css`
- I've checked to see if the issue was the padding and margin of the header tags (h1 -h6) and the paragraph tags.
- I've used the chrome browser Inspector tool(I'm not sure if that is what you call it) to delete elements until only the header and footer remain and the gap still remains.

**My Theories:**

- something with `boodtrap.css`

[the main issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFWhA.jpg)

Any suggestions?

Comment: is it live? can you post the link of your site?

Comment: yes it is. the link is http://ekm16.anastasioumedia.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this.. the height of your `navbar` overlap and the toggler canver you need to center it..

```
section#sp-menu-main {
   height: 40px;
}

a#offcanvas-toggler {
   padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: @AnastasiouDesign if I'm not mistaken what you want is just to shorten the gap between navbar and banner right?

Comment: @AnastasiouDesign so you want the image to stick in nav bar?

Comment: I see you can use `@media on that specific resolution` then add this code on `article.item.item-page { position: relative; top: -32px; }`